# Error while importing .csv file int mongodb

Tags: mongodb, csv

while importing a fairly big .csv file into mongodb using mongoimport, i have rectified and corrected every error except one that says: open "some.csv file" access is denied. not able to understand where i went wrong here. access is open to this file though.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try using a copy of said file? It will probably work - I'm not suggesting this as a solution, it's just a test

Comment: If you are using mac or ubuntu user try mongoimport command with sudo

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoimport is probably trying to acquire a write lock on the file - and the file is already opened or you have insufficient rights - if intrusive alternatives are not an option, simply copying the file should suffice.